# Testing fragment creation and expire fragment in Rails (3.0.7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fragment-caching

I'm attempting to implement fragment caching in my application. It displays a lot of data that rarely changes so I figured that fragment caching would be the best solution for some performance problems I've been having.

I'm using Rail's built-in fragment caching and cache sweepers, but I can't seem to find any good way of testing the creation/expiration of the fragments (using rspec and friends).

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**Clarification:** All I really want to test is that the appropriate fragments are expired, not that anything in particular is going in or coming out of the cache.

Comment: IMO you shouldn't test the expiration since that behavior is already tested in Rails, in fact and by default caching is disabled in the test environment, so maybe you should tests the methods or actions that actually trigger the cache creation or expiration.

Comment: All I really want to test is that whenever a certain action is called, the appropriate caches are expired. I really don't care what (if anything is in the cache).

Comment: i would also like to test this because in my case, the needed fragments are not going to be expired.

Answer (score 1):

With mocha it would be something like this:

```
UserController.any_instance.expects(:expire_fragment).with('cache_key')
```

The only thing we care about with this test is that the method actually gets called with the appropriate arguments not if the method actually does the job.

Used in rspec:

```
it 'expires the awesome user cache' do
  UserController.any_instance.expects(:expire_fragment).with('awesome_user_cache').once

  post :create, id: user.id, ect...
end
```